# Can't draw a bitmap on a desktop using GDI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I wanted to make program that just draw a picture on a desktop using GDI, but it doesn't show anything. I checked if there's any error and it shown me error code 2.
This is my code

```
BITMAP bitMap;
HBITMAP hBitmap = reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP>(LoadImageA(0, Globals::bmpPath.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP, 1536,864, LR_LOADFROMFILE));

HDC whdc = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(whdc);

SelectObject(hdcMem,hBitmap);
GetObject(reinterpret_cast<HGDIOBJ>(hBitmap), sizeof(bitMap), &bitMap);

BitBlt(whdc, 0, 0, 1536,864, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
```

It's in while(true) btw.

Comment: The desktop window isn't yours. You cannot render onto it and hope that the actual owner of that window won't just go ahead and remove anything you put there. If you need to render, create a window.

Comment: If you need `reinterpret_cast` you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `BitBlt` is supposed to transfer bits to `hwdc`, which is in fact a `GetDC(NULL)`. You need there a real DC from a real window like `myTargetDC=GetDC(hWnd)`. But better use WM_PAINT handler and use the de from BeginPaint instead of drawing it each 200 milliseconds, let the operation system to decide when to draw it.

Use following function to load an image and use where you want it:

```cpp
HBITMAP loadImageFromFileW(wchar_t* fileName)
{
    char* buf = 0;
    HBITMAP btRet = 0;

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(fileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    DWORD dwFileSizeHigh;
    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize( hFile, &dwFileSizeHigh );
    buf = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, fileSize);
    DWORD read;
    ReadFile(hFile, buf, fileSize, &read, 0);
    
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmpfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER *)buf;
    BITMAPINFO* pbmInfo = (BITMAPINFO*)(buf + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));

    if(pbmInfo->bmiHeader.biCompression == BI_RGB)
    {
        HDC hdcSrc = CreateDCW(L"DISPLAY", 0, 0, 0);
        btRet = CreateDIBitmap(hdcSrc, &pbmInfo->bmiHeader, CBM_INIT, buf + bmpfh->bfOffBits, pbmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        DeleteDC(hdcSrc);
    }

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, buf);

    return btRet;
}
```

Use it at once somewhere on initializing the progam:

```cpp
    hBitmapBmpFile = loadImageFromFileW(L"yourbmp.bmp");
```

And use hBitmapBmpFile

```cpp
    case WM_PAINT:
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hDC= BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            {
                HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
                HGDIOBJ hbmOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmapBmpFile);
                BITMAP bm;
                GetObject(hBitmapBmpFile, sizeof(bm), &bm);
                BitBlt(hDC, 10, 190, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                DeleteDC(hdcMem);
            }
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
```

Comment: Ok, it wasn't working because the path was wrong.. bruh xD